# D3.JS datamaps country name variable

Tags: javascript, variables, d3.js, country, datamaps

I want to enter the country name as a variable but I can't.

```
var interval_1=window.setInterval(function() {
  var name = "USA";
  map.updateChoropleth({
  name : colors(Math.random() * 10),
  });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: too few information, can you be more specific, it could be really nice if you add a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) would be nice

Comment: Thank you, burningfuses has replied to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use a variable as a key in a JavaScript object literal.
This has already been answered here: [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

This would give the result you expect:

```
var interval_1=window.setInterval(function() {
    var name = "USA";
    var country = {}
    country[name] = colors(Math.random() * 10)
    map.updateChoropleth(country);
}, 2000);
```